# Visual Studio with IE9: Debug window order is messed up

Tags: visual-studio-2010, internet-explorer-9

I've just 'upgraded' to IE9. I'm running VS2010 and I used to be quite happy with the Quick Watch window and how it worked. Now when I try and debug the window is messed up in that the variables and methods are all mixed up. Is there any way to fix this?

[image]

It's making debugging a real pain as nothing is in any order that I can see. Not even alphabetical.